# Long Text from database and show it in paragraph form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Help me guys. I want it to show as a paragraph form the long text. This is my code

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","dbparagraph");
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tblparagraph");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{
$show = $row['LongText'];
echo "<p>" .$show. "</p>";
}
```

Then the wrong output is like this.

```
This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
```

But I want like this one.

```
       This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
 This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
 This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
```

How can i do this? is this jQuery or Javascript? Help me please.
Thanks in advance :).

I use table word-wrap: break-word; Don't bother to solve this thanks :).

Comment: This is not Javascript or jQuery, this is PHP. Could you paste output source? You can view the output source by pressing `ctrl + u` keys in web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using nl2br() function.

Code:

```
$show='       This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
 This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
 This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.';

echo nl2br($show);
```

Result:

```
       This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.<br />
 This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.<br />
 This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
```

Which should display correctly on your page.

Alternatively, if you are outputting logs, then do something like this:

```
echo "<p><pre>$show</pre></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want the text to remain within a html element such as a div container, then you should use the [css word-wrap property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp). See

But if you want to divide your text into paragraphs of certain length, then you can use the [Php Word Wrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function